# gmaps4rails add image to infowindow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have enjoyed using you gmaps_4_rails gem and am impressed with the ease of configuring it. The only problem that I have had and I have spent a great deal of time trying to get it working is how to add an image to an infowindow. I cant get the example:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "<img src=\"#{self.picture}\"> #{self.name}"
end
```

to work. I want to be able to do something like this in the infowindow     /public/images/#{name}.jpg width= 25 height = 32.

I eventually want to store the images on amazon s3 but have been working on my local macbook  to get the process working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "<img src='/images/#{name}.jpg' width='25' height='32'> #{name}"
end
```

Have a look here to be sure of what you do:
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Security-Warning